# char array and pointer C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

This is my program. The output for char s3[2] = "q" is "QC++" when it should just be "Q". I guess I have to reset the pointer, but i'm not sure how.

```
void myToUpperCase(const char *source, char *dest){

    for(int i = 0; *(source + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        *(dest + i) = toupper(*(source + i));
    }
}

char s2[20] = "#c++";
char s3[2] = "q";
char result[20];

myToUpperCase(s2, result);
cout << "- s2 (\"" << s2 << "\") myToUpper() -> " << result << " => "     << ((strcmp(result, "#C++") == 0) ? "correct.\n" : "INCORRECT.\n");

myToUpperCase(s3, result);
cout << "- s3 (\"" << s3 << "\") myToUpper() -> " << result << " => "     << ((strcmp(result, "Q") == 0) ? "correct.\n" : "INCORRECT.\n");
```

Comment: `myToUpperCase` doesn't NUL-terminate the output buffer. It still holds whatever garbage was left over from prior activity.

Comment: Also, once again relevant: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Answer (score 0):

When you transform your array, you terminate your loop at terminating null which doesn't get copied and so when you print your transformed string, it keeps on printing the content of the memory until first random 0 it encounters. This is why you get garbage. Try this for a change:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

void myToUpperCase(const char *source, char *dest)
{
    while ((*dest++ = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(*source++))) != '\0');
}

int main()
{ 
    char s2[20] = "#c++";
    char s3[2] = "q";
    char result[20];

    myToUpperCase(s2, result);
    std::cout << "- s2 (\"" << s2 << "\") myToUpper() -> " << result << " => " << ((std::strcmp(result, "#C++") == 0) ? "correct.\n" : "INCORRECT.\n");

    myToUpperCase(s3, result);
    std::cout << "- s3 (\"" << s3 << "\") myToUpper() -> " << result << " => " << ((std::strcmp(result, "Q") == 0) ? "correct.\n" : "INCORRECT.\n");
}
```

https://ideone.com/lj1HC5

```
- s2 ("#c++") myToUpper() -> #C++ => correct.
- s3 ("q") myToUpper() -> Q => correct.
```

The while loop terminates when it gets to '\0' only this time terminating null is copied already.

Answer (score 0):

You could call memset before calling myToUpperCase to prepare your buffer.  That's often helpful.

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

So...

```
memset(result, 0, 20);
```

Comment: `memset` is overkill. You only need to set one character to null to terminate the string.

Comment: Yes, but having a buffer full of garbage on the way in is not necessarily good practice.  It is definitely not helpful for n00bs.

Answer (score -4):

you should make it so your function returns a pointer to the string, and create the pointer dest in the function and return it, like this you have a situation:
the first call of the function finishes, dest is "#C++", then calls it again and just replaces the # with Q

Comment: The question is about why the strings are malformed and it's because there's no terminating null in the output string and because the same buffer is used for both output strings. It is coincidence that there's a terminating null in that buffer to stop the output after 4 characters. Your answer does not fix the bug in his code and adds extra complexity. It is dangerous to allocate memory in a function and expect the caller to free it. It can also hurt performance if that matters.